# Nexus 7 Touchscreen Mouse Freezes

Tags: mouse, screen, ubuntu-touch, 13.04, nexus-7

I'm running ubuntu 13.04 on my Nexus 7, and all is good until the mouse stops working. The "button1" gets stuck. I was wondering if anyone knows the name of the mouse module being used (so I could map a key to modprobe it), or perhaps an alternate way to reset the mouse.

Any information helps. I've done extensive googling and nothing has been of use.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've seen something like 'elan touchpad' in the 'scan keys' setting of OnBoard. Is that what you are looking for?